External wall boards
I am residing my 1950 cape and upon removing the singles and tar paper I found that the boards underneath have spaces between them, an eight to a quarter in in some places. Can I caulk these before installing tyvek or will it affect air circulation?

50s were not known for air sealing homes, so most were/are quite drafty/did not need extra intake fresh for burning fuels/living.

I was going to suggest humidity expansion gaps, but this is probably pine, which moves relatively little with humidity change...

It is not uncommon to find a few spaces that small in your siding and roof decking. Caulking will not affect anything because there's not any air flow between those spaces but caulking isn't necessary. Too much spacing can affect the hold down nailing of the shingles if the nails go through the spacing.

OP said residing.  So not sure roof deck is involved.  More like 1x10s planks nailed to wall studs.  Roof is the common place for shingles/tar paper, but possible it was used for siding also.

@crip659  The "singles" and tar paper threw me off.
